# Change image hue libgdx

Tags: image, image-processing, libgdx, rgb, hsv

I am trying to create an app in which I have a single cloth picture (a women ethnic top, with obviously shadow effect to make it look real) and I want the user to click on a color tab on the right side, so that the color of the top changes, but the shadow effect should remain the same.

I am using libgdx for this. I have created a texture from the input top image and used linear filter to smoothen it. the original top looks like: [image: Original Top]

The new cloth that I want to place on the top is: [image: New Cloth]

Initially I converted every pixel of the shirt from rgb space to hsv space. I tried 4 methods to achieve the above problem:

1. I used hue,saturation from new cloth, and brightness(I have to take shadows, they have low brightness) from the shirt. The problem here is the fabric color becomes light due to the low brightness in the top (brightness comes from the top). It produces the below image:
   [image]
2. I used hue,saturation from the new cloth, and set a cut off for the brightness from the top. 70% is the cut off. The problem here is that the shadows are not clear as the fabric is dark:
   [image]
3. I used z-score to calculate brightness at each pixel. The z score for brightness at every pixel in the blouse is used to adjust the brightness in the cloth. z score for every pixel is made the same, and the brightness for the fabric is calculates. This image is also not looking much acceptable:
   [image]

I need a help on what approach should I use to achieve the above scenario. Am I on the right track, or I am doing something completely wrong. May be I should remove the outer color to see if the top looks realistic (since the background and top color become same, is this the reason for an unrealistic result?

Comment: Try setting this up in Gimp. Put the image on one layer and fill the second layer with a color. Then try different blend options for the top layer until you find what you want. You can find the equations for the Gimp blend modes online and use the one you picked to create a shader that does the same thing with the vertex color of your Sprite.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - Thanks for the help. But this will become too manual in case where I have more than 50 new fabrics, and there is a new fabric coming in every week. I want to create a system for the non technical people who just want to generate a new colored top just by clicking. So I have to code everything within the libgdx/java code. May be by using some other library. I am still figuring it out.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my suggestion. The result is a single shader that you can use to recolor anything in your app.

Comment: Yes I tried it in gimp and one of the ways worked for me. I used the equation to work on the pixmap of the image. Thanks for the help @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not really sure if LibGDX is proper  and best tool for the things you want to implement. For me it rather looks like a job for a library connected with image processing like [OpenCV mobile](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) for example.

The truth is that I haven't used it yet (although I have some experience with OpenCV itself) and the fast googleing didin't return any "official" tutorial how to integrate this with libGDX (although I'm pretty sure it is possible).

---

Anyway - if you want to use LibGDX to operate on colour like this you have a [SpriteBatch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html)'es method

```
    void setColor(Color tint)
```

that you can use for colorizing the SpriteBatch you are using for rendering things.

Due to default generated project the effect is as you can see:

- without tint:

  ```
  batch.begin();
  batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
  batch.end();
  ```

  [image: Sprite Batch without tint]
- tint applied:

  ```
  batch.begin();
  batch.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
  batch.end();
  ```

  [image: Sprite Batch with tint applied]

---

Please also notice that tinting image is *naive* that means that it will colorize also background so you need to cut the image from it's background and save it in .PNG format.

Take a look at this example:

[image: Tint image without background]

Comment: I am doing this in Libgdx as I will do further modifications in this, like creating a mesh and moving the triangles. Also, I guess the above thing will work only for predefined colors, or solid colors. I have more fabrics to put on the top. Some are stripes, chequered etc. So in that case, I think the above thing will not work.

Comment: Predefined - not - you can define your on RGB value like `Color c = new Color(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 1);`. Solid - yes unfortunately tint is setting just one color to whole batch. Although you could cut your photo to slices and render them overlaping each other with anouther tint set to achieve for example stripes. Avoiding manual iterating over pixmap and colorizing pixels with some procedure I'm not sure is there at least one another solution to be honest...

Comment: I guess some manipulations with the hsv space needs to be done here. I am not sure how it can be done. I wish to do something similar to http://www.houseofblouse.com/design/u-neck-2 ; infact something better than that.

Comment: The example you've provided does not look like manipulating color but rather texturing with predefined textures - maybe this is the way you should try? Changing color can be insufficient for your purposes

Comment: Yes, a number of pre-defined textures including floral ones, zigzag ones, dotted ones and many more. But will slicing work for zigzag designs? Also, floral designs etc will be tough to handle by cutting photo into slices and rendering them over each other. Am i right?